# Swift: Mailgun 401 response code--No valid API key provided

Tags: swift, xcode, httpresponse, mailgun, urlsession

So I have my send email function as seen below:

```
func email() {
    let session = URLSession.shared
    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: NSURL(string: "https://api.mailgun.net/v3/sandbox################################/messages")! as URL)

    request.httpMethod = "POST"
    let credentials = "api:key-################################-########-########"
    request.setValue("Basic \(credentials.toBase64())", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")

    let data = "from: Swift Email <(test@test.com)>&to: [myemail@gmail.com,(myemail@gmail.com)]&subject:Hello&text:Testing_some_Mailgun_awesomness"
    request.httpBody = data.data(using: String.Encoding.ascii)

    let task = session.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest, completionHandler: {(data, response, error) in
        if let error = error {
            print(error)
        }
        if let response = response {
            print("url = \(response.url!)")
            print("response = \(response)")
            let httpResponse = response as! HTTPURLResponse
            print("response code = \(httpResponse.statusCode)")
        }
    })
    task.resume()
}
```

So I guess either my API key is wrong or my request URL is wrong. To find my request URL, I went to https://app.mailgun.com/app/dashboard and then scrolled down to the Sending Domains section and copied that. To get my API key I went to https://app.mailgun.com/app/account/security/api_keys and just copied the Private API Key. I'm really not sure why I'm getting this invalid code--thank you in advance if you figure it out!

Side note: Not really sure if the data constant is set up right (in terms of missing or having too many parens), so if you could check that too that would be phenomenal.

Comment: I'd suggest that you try out `kamailgun-swift`: https://github.com/KevinAo22/kamailgun-swift

Comment: @excitedmicrobe I actually already tried that this morning--for some reason, when I run the pod init, and put in pod 'Mailgun-In-Swift', it shows the installs as working correctly in terminal (Alamofire, Mailgun-In-Swift, and ObjectMapper all install)--then, when I open up the xc workspace file and try to just type in import Mailgun-In-Swift, it doesn't recognize the module so idk what's going on with it

Comment: When I type in that import as well, it also says 'Consecutive statements on a line must be separated by ';'' and 'expression expected after unary operator (the -)', and 'expressions not allowed at the top level.'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a software called "paw" it helps forming REST API call for Xcode, curl, php, etc.

I don't know if this could help you

```
class MyRequestController {
    func sendRequest(somevar: String, completion: @escaping (Books) -> Void) {
        /* Configure session, choose between:
           * defaultSessionConfiguration
           * ephemeralSessionConfiguration
           * backgroundSessionConfigurationWithIdentifier:
         And set session-wide properties, such as: HTTPAdditionalHeaders,
         HTTPCookieAcceptPolicy, requestCachePolicy or timeoutIntervalForRequest.
         */
        let sessionConfig = URLSessionConfiguration.default

        /* Create session, and optionally set a URLSessionDelegate. */
        let session = URLSession(configuration: sessionConfig, delegate: nil, delegateQueue: nil)

        /* Create the Request:
            (POST https://api.mailgun.net/v3/YOUR_DOMAIN_NAME/messages)
         */

        guard var URL = URL(string: "https://api.mailgun.net/v3/YOUR_DOMAIN_NAME/messages") else {return}
        var request = URLRequest(url: URL)
        request.httpMethod = "POST"

        // Headers

        request.addValue("Basic YXBpOllPVVJfQVBJX0tFWQ==", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
        request.addValue("multipart/form-data; charset=utf-8; boundary=__X_PAW_BOUNDARY__", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")

        // Body

        let bodyString = "--__X_PAW_BOUNDARY__\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"from\"\r\n\r\n'Excited User <mailgun@YOUR_DOMAIN_NAME>'\r\n--__X_PAW_BOUNDARY__\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"to\"\r\n\r\nYOU@YOUR_DOMAIN_NAME\r\n--__X_PAW_BOUNDARY__\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"to\"\r\n\r\nbar@example.com\r\n--__X_PAW_BOUNDARY__\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"subject\"\r\n\r\n'Hello'\r\n--__X_PAW_BOUNDARY__\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"text\"\r\n\r\n'Testing some Mailgun awesomeness!'\r\n--__X_PAW_BOUNDARY__--\r\n"
        request.httpBody = bodyString.data(using: .utf8, allowLossyConversion: true)

        /* Start a new Task */
        let task = session.dataTask(with: request, completionHandler: { (data: Data?, response: URLResponse?, error: Error?) -> Void in
            if (error == nil) {
                // Success
                let statusCode = (response as! HTTPURLResponse).statusCode
                print("URL Session Task Succeeded: HTTP \(statusCode)")
            }
            else {
                // Failure
                print("URL Session Task Failed: %@", error!.localizedDescription);
            }
        })
        task.resume()
        session.finishTasksAndInvalidate()
    }
}
```

**** and you CALL this function a bit like this

```
MyRequestController().sendRequest(somevar: "something")
```

take a look at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=44APgBnapag for more details
this tutorial show how to do REST API calls with Xcode, this example it scan a barcode, send the scanned code via a function that calls the API and return infos...